# How to represent integer ARRAY in JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

How to represent column definition of `integer ARRAY` in a java @Entity class using JPA, is there a native mapping or should we define columnDefinition for this

```
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html
scores integer ARRAY,
```

Answer (score 0):

Natively with java and spring, it can be quite tricky to do and manage the whole process, it is done using `@ElementCollection`.

However using the library `Hypersistence Utils` from Vlad Mihalcea makes it relatively easy and straight forward.

Add the appropriate maven dependency of the library to your project. Then in your entity, it is represented as such;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
@TypeDef(name = "int-array", typeClass = IntArrayType.class) // declaring the type
public class MyEntity{

    @Type(type = "int-array") // using the declared type
    @Column(
        name = "scores",
        columnDefinition = "integer[]"
    )
    private int[] scores;
}
```

More info on the [library](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils). An [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) to help with the type mapping.